# SAX Feature Not Supported in Spring Boot 2.6.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, sax

Spring boot 2.6.1 supports logback 1.2.7

I've added the following dependencies in project

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But the build fails with below exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: SAX feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' not supported.
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory.setFeature(JXSAXParserFactory.java:272)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:82)
    ... 44 more
```

In SaxEventRecorder.class, it fails while building the SAX parser

```java
    private SAXParser buildSaxParser() throws JoranException {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            spf.setValidating(false);
            //spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
            spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
            spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
            spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            return spf.newSAXParser();
        } catch (Exception pce) {
            String errMsg = "Parser configuration error occurred";
            addError(errMsg, pce);
            throw new JoranException(errMsg, pce);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to override the implementation?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same issue during an upgrade. It wasn't a Spring issue, and you don't want to override the implementation yourself.

`SAXParserFactory` is an abstract class - it can have multiple implementations. The `newInstance` method picks the last/top implementation on the classpath.

I had found that I had an "extra" implementation on my classpath due to a dependency having their own implementation of `SAXParserFactory` rather than the 'typical' implementation that Logback expects. And this "extra" `SAXParserFactory` did not support the feature that Logback is trying to enable.

I had to explicitly declare a xerces implementation higher in my dependencies in order for a "real" implementation to take precedence over the other "extra" implementation on the classpath.

So my advice is for you to see what implementations of this abstract class you have (I could easily see this using the IntelliJ IDE), then manage/re-arrange your dependencies so that a proper implementation supporting the feature has a higher precedence on your classpath.

Comment: The implementation to use also can be defined via "-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl" as java command line argument

Comment: In case someone likes to know, I fixed it by adding `xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.2`. In my case the error was caused because I need the `com.oracle.database.xml:xmlparserv2` dependency. The xerces was added as the first dependency in the pom.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is not exactly what you're looking for, but for my project we made a decision to exclude this parser:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8-production</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But if you really need it, I suggest you to look at @matzeihnsein's answer and to upgrade your version. Doing so also helped me.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was that we used an old dependency

```
 <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
 <version>12.1.0.2</version>
```

updating to

```
<groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
<version>12.2.0.1</version>
```

ojdbc8 solved my issue!